# Function which outputs statistics for each variable combination

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matrix, vector

I want to write function `combinations_features(y, x)` which go through all combinations containing three variables and will output r squared, adjusted r squared, AIC and BIC for each combination.

**My solution**

```
combinations_features <- function(y, x) {
  
  # Define empty vectors to store statistics 
  feature_vec_1 <- feature_vec_2 <-
    feature_vec_3 <- feature_vec_4 <- c()
  
  # Obtaining all combinations containing three variables  
  comb_names <- utils::combn(colnames(x), 3)
  
  # For each combination obtain wanted statistics
  for (i in 1:ncol(comb_names)) {
    feature_vec_1 <- append(
      feature_vec_1, summary(lm(y ~ ., data = x[, comb_names[, i]]))$adj.r.squared
    )
    feature_vec_2 <- append(
      feature_vec_2, summary(lm(y ~ ., data = x[, comb_names[, i]]))$r.squared
    )
    feature_vec_3 <- append(
      feature_vec_3, AIC(lm(y ~ ., data = x[, comb_names[, i]]))
    )
    feature_vec_4 <- append(
      feature_vec_4, BIC(lm(y ~ ., data = x[, comb_names[, i]]))
    )
  }
  
  # Assign everything into data frame
  
  data.frame(
    "Adj R2" = feature_vec_1, "R2" = feature_vec_2,
    "AIC" = feature_vec_3, "BIC" = feature_vec_4
  )
}
```

Let's see how it works - define some artificial data and give it to the function.

```
set.seed(42)
predictors <- data.frame(rnorm(100), runif(100), rexp(100), rpois(100, 1))
dependent <- rnorm(100)
    
> combinations_features(dependent, predictors)
         Adj.R2          R2      AIC      BIC
1 -0.0283756015 0.002787295 276.2726 289.2985
2  0.0000677269 0.030368705 273.4678 286.4937
3 -0.0011990695 0.029140296 273.5944 286.6203
4  0.0015404392 0.031796789 273.3204 286.3463
```

However I find this code very inefficient due to these two things:

(1) Loop - I looped it over columns of matrices `comb_names`, I wonder if it can be omitted somehow

(2) Length of the code - This code is huge! Due to the fact that I define `feature_vec` for each statistics and append to them separately. I wonder if assigning to them can be done somehow by one command.

Could you please give me hand with improving my code by telling if it's possible to apply (1) or (2) ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this, which relies on `bind_rows()` from tidyverse?  I don't think there's a way to avoid looping over the combinations, but `lapply` makes everything a little neater, IMHO.

```
combinations_features1 <- function(y, x) {
  comb_names <- utils::combn(colnames(x), 3)
  bind_rows(
    lapply(
      1:ncol(comb_names),
      function(z) {
        m <- lm(y ~ ., data = x[, comb_names[,z]])
        s <- summary(m)
        tibble(Adj.R2=s$adj.r.squared, R2=s$r.squared, AIC=AIC(m), BIC=BIC(m))
      }
    )
  ) 
}

combinations_features1(dependent, predictors)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
      Adj.R2      R2   AIC   BIC
       <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 -0.0284    0.00279  276.  289.
2  0.0000677 0.0304   273.  286.
3 -0.00120   0.0291   274.  287.
4  0.00154   0.0318   273.  286.
```

`bind_rows()`, if given a list, binds the elements of the list into a single `data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Same idea as above, just directly applying `lapply` to the list of combinations would also work:

```r
combinations_features <- function(y,x){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(utils::combn(colnames(x), 3, simplify=FALSE), 
    function(i){
      f1 <- lm(y ~ ., data=x[, i])
      data.frame(Adj.R2=summary(f1)$adj.r.squared,
                 R2=summary(f1)$r.squared,
                 AIC=AIC(f1), BIC=BIC(f1))
    }))
}
```